# Article use in "this computer has 8GB RAM" or "this computer has an 8GB RAM"?

Tags: articles

Which of the following pair of alternatives is correct:

1. This computer has **an** 8GB RAM.
2. This computer has 8GB RAM.

Should the article *an* be there?

Comment: Additionally, should you say *This computer had 8GB **of** RAM*?

Comment: Use ***an** 8GB*, not ***a** 8GB*.

Comment: @NVZ Actually, don't use either (at least not in the context of RAM—“an 8 GB hard drive” is a different matter, of course).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was not answering the question, but merely mentioning the use of ***an*** is better in front of ***eight***. Looks like OP has edited the question as per my comment.

Comment: "an 8 GB RAM" would refer to a single memory bar inserted in the computer. "8 GB [of] RAM" refers to the total RAM of the computer (possibly got from 2 or 4 memory bars)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: what are you talking about? My laptop has 8GB of RAM.

Comment: @TonyK Exactly. It has 8 GB of RAM, not an 8 GB RAM.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: yes, I see now what you were saying.

Comment: @Graffito That would be an 8 GB RAM module/stick/whateveryouwannacallit. Calling it ‘a RAM’ is, at least in my experience, very uncommon.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - My purpose was just to highlight the difference bettween OP's expressions. In the sense of a memory device, I would also add the word "module/device/stick/drive". However, The [tech term computer](http://techterms.com/definition/ram) dictionary defines RAM as : *RAM is made up of small memory chips that form a memory module. These modules are installed in the RAM slots on the motherboard of your computer*. Another dic. defines its as: *an integrated circuit memory chip allows information to be stored or accessed in any order and all storage locations are equally accessible*

Comment: "This computer has 8GB RAM" is slightly more idiomatic, but there's no syntactic or semantic problem with "This computer has an 8GB RAM".

Comment: @Graffito - There would be nothing wrong with saying "This computer has an 8GB memory."  Substituting "RAM" for "memory" is something that many techies might do.  Using "RAM" does not imply that the "RAM" is all in one chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It has eight gigabytes of RAM
>
> It has 8GB of RAM

This is correct, just like

> It holds 5 gallons of water.
>
> It takes 10 hours of my day.

It is unusual to use both a number and an article: you only need one determiner.

Comment: 8GB or RAM -- which is it?

Answer (score -2):

Always "8GB RAM" and never "an 8GB RAM"… today.

Until about 1980, the cognoscenti called it RAM but Joe Public needed the full "random access memory" and both might very well have said or thought of "an 8GB random access memory".

Whether either would have said "an 8GB RAM" would have depended on whether they thought of "RAM" as the abbreviation it really is, or as the word in and of itself that it has become, although that was how long ago?

Full-out, random access memory was quantifiable and comparable to cars or grains, but the acronym RAM has become collective and comparable to traffic, sugar or salt.

Comment: Uh… what? Did someone not like that, please?